Linux / Docker Error `No such file or directory: '/opt/bin/credentials.sh' ` when clearly file exists with proper read permissions
I am setting up the AWS CLI in my GCP Cloud Run environment to use AWS STS for authentication using assume-role functionality following this docs. I'm using a Docker image to build the Cloud Run image, ensuring the AWS CLI is installed and configured correctly. Dockerfile for the same is as follows
FROM node:20-alpine

# Install necessary packages and dependencies
USER root
RUN apk update && \
    apk add --no-cache jq curl unzip && \
    apk add --no-cache aws-cli

RUN aws --version

RUN pwd
COPY package*.json ./
COPY credentials.sh /opt/bin/credentials.sh

# Ensure the script has the correct line endings and is executable
RUN dos2unix /opt/bin/credentials.sh && chmod 755 /opt/bin/credentials.sh

RUN mkdir -p ~/.aws
RUN mkdir -p /root/.aws/
COPY config ~/.aws/config
COPY config /root/.aws/config

RUN ls -la /opt/bin
RUN cat /opt/bin/credentials.sh

# Run the script directly to ensure it executes
RUN /opt/bin/credentials.sh

RUN aws configure list

ENTRYPOINT ["node", "index.js"]


The content of the ~/.aws/config file is as follows:
[default]
credential_process = /opt/bin/credentials.sh

credential_process was suggested to remove hardcoding access id and secret for greater security.
After configuring all this, i wanted to check if AWS is correctly configured by running aws configure list using Docker RUN command.
However, when I build the image, I encounter the following error during the RUN aws configure list step:
[23/23] RUN aws configure list:
0.730 
0.730 [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/bin/credentials.sh'

I have verified that the file exists and has the correct permissions: Below is the ls command showing the file in the correct location (/opt/bin/credentials.sh).
#25 [19/23] RUN ls -la /opt/bin
#25 0.188 total 20
#25 0.189 drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 May 31 14:25 .
#25 0.189 drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 May 31 14:25 ..
#25 0.189 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           714 May 31 14:24 credentials.sh

Despite this, the AWS CLI cannot find the credentials.sh script.
I’ve Tried
Checked file existence and permissions: The file exists and is executable.
Ensured correct line endings: I used dos2unix to ensure the script has Unix-style line endings.

Why is the AWS CLI unable to find the credentials.sh file even though it exists with the correct permissions? How can I resolve this issue?
Futher note:
I am able to see the contents of the file when doing cat /opt/bin/credentials.sh. Only when running it it throws the permission error.

What's in the shebang line of the file?

@tripleee #!/bin/bash

And is /bin/bash present in the image?

No. That seems to be the error. I changed the shebang to use sh and itseems to work fine. Thanks a lot @tripleee. please share that as an answer. can accept it.
